Slavery and soil quality
I am reading the book Capitalism and Slavery: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitalism_and_Slavery
The author argues that, in a historical context, working a plantation with slaves, in comparison to hired labor, resulted in a faster degradation of soil quality. The reason for this, according to the author, is the lower work motivation of slaves compared to hired labor.
What concrete actions or omissions of slaves or hired workers could lead to this effect? What could be a connection between labor quality and soil quality? Any suggestions are welcome, thanks

Could you quote the relevant section/passage?

It might be a question of how intensively the land was worked under each scenario. Did one scenario have a rotating plot of land that was left fallow for a year, so it could recover? Were other forms of land care or land abuse used? Was a question of greed by the one group & not the other that lead to such practices, if they occurred?

@thosphor. It's a few pages, so I tried to distill the argument here

@Carsten Does the author of this publication propose any mechanism, even if merely speculative, conjectured, or hypothetical, by which "lower work motivation of slaves compared to hired labor ... resulted in a faster degradation of soil quality"? What indicators of soil quality are being considered, and how are they being assessed?  I am only familiar with one particular method of assessment, the German Bodenwertzahl.

@njuffa: The author was quite vague on the mechanisms. My hypothesis would be that there are certain actions that can be done to improve soil quality (e.g. plowing would come to my mind). If those tasks are done in a bad quality, this would have a negative effect on soil quality. But I'm really not an expert here...

sounds like an unsupported assertion, does the author offer an justification?

@John I think that's the point of asking the question here; the OP likely feels the same way, and is curious to find if the assertion can be supported.

slavery ended but the same people continued working on farms doeing the same  type of work as before,this removes a large part of the before vs after slavery soil quality part of the question.

@trondhansen: The argument is certainly not about the characteristics of the people, it is rather about how they are incentivised. Slaves have little to win from high quality work. As hired laber however, you can benefit from high quality work through bonuses or higher wages

@uhoh if the author posits it with justification it can be dismissed with no justification.

@John that's certainly an option that any given reader might choose, yes.
